# Polars Replacing Values Greater than the Max of Another Polars DataFrame Within Groups

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I have 2 DataFrames:

```py
import polars as pl

df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
        "index": [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 8],
    }
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
        "index": [3, 4, 7, 2, 7, 10],
    }
)
```

I want to cap the `index` in `df2` using the **largest index** of each group in `df1`. The groups in two DataFrames are the same.

expected output for `df2`:

```py
shape: (6, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ index │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ A     ┆ 3     │
│ A     ┆ 4     │
│ A     ┆ 5     │
│ B     ┆ 2     │
│ B     ┆ 7     │
│ B     ┆ 8     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the max per group over df1, then [`clip`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.clip.html) df2:

```
out = df2.with_columns(
    pl.col('index').clip(
        upper_bound=df1.select(pl.col('index').max().over('group'))['index']
    )
)
```

Output:

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ index │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ A     ┆ 3     │
│ A     ┆ 4     │
│ A     ┆ 5     │
│ B     ┆ 2     │
│ B     ┆ 7     │
│ B     ┆ 8     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

Alternatively, if the two groups are not necessarily the same in both dataframes, you could [`group_by.max`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.max.html) then align with [`join`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
        "index": [1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 7],
    }
)

df2 = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
        "index": [3, 4, 7, 2, 7, 8, 9],
    }
)

out = df2.with_columns(
    pl.col('index').clip(
        upper_bound=df2.join(df1.group_by('group').max(), on='group')['index_right']
    )
)
```

Output:

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ index │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ A     ┆ 3     │
│ A     ┆ 4     │
│ A     ┆ 5     │
│ B     ┆ 2     │
│ B     ┆ 7     │
│ B     ┆ 7     │
│ B     ┆ 7     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please accepted my sincere apology for the badly designed case. I have changed the original case so that the `max value` for each group is different.

Comment: I noticed and updated. Your explanation was clear though ;)